# Postgres jsonb_insert Insert Only When Object Doesn't Already Exist

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to add items to a JSON array using `jsonb_insert` as:

`jsob_insert(document, '{path,to,array,0}','{"key":"value"}')`

This inserts `{"key":"value"}` to the head of `array`. However, I want to do this insert iff the JSON object `{"key":"value"}` does not already exist in the array. Currently, it just adds it to the array without caring about duplicacy (which is how it is intended to work). I am just wondering if there is a way to take care of duplicate records this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap that call in a `case` that checks whether the object already exists in the array:

```
with invars as (
  select '{
    "path": {
      "to": {
        "array": [
          {
            "key": "value"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }'::jsonb as document
)
select case 
         when jsonb_path_exists(document, '$.path.to.array[*].key ? (@ == "value")')
           then document
         else jsonb_insert(document, '{path,to,array,0}', '{"key": "value"}')
       end as desired_result,
       jsonb_insert(document, '{path,to,array,0}', '{"key": "value"}') as old_result
  from invars;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=52c2ce219cfa2a69eb84cb1faee85008)*